# TreeViewer refresh/update specific TreeColumn

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, treeviewer

Is there any way to refresh/update just a specific `TreeColumn` in a `TreeViewer`? 
I currently have a feature in my `TreeViewer` that cand hide/show a `TreeColumn`. When a column is hidden, the values for that column can go out of sync with my Model. Thats why I need to refresh to Column when I enable it again and the operation of getting the value for cells of the column is very expensive.

I have a solution but I'm hoping that there is a better solution (maybe something out-of-the-box). I managed to define my `LabelProvider` as an Inner Class in the class that contains the `TreeViewer` (`CustomTreeView extends ViewPart`). `CustomTreeView` will have the method `update(TreeColumn)` which will:

1. store the `TreeColumn` in a private field of the inline `LabelProvider` class.
2. call `TreeViewer.refresh()`
3. set the `TreeColumn` field of the inner `LabelProvider` to null.

The `update(ViewerCell cell)` method of the `LabelProvider` will check if the `ViewerCell` belongs to the `TreeColumn` stored in the `LabelProvider` and refresh it if needed.

What do you think?
Thanks in advance.